# Hyperbolic functions and the Saint Louis arch

Tags: calculus

I was trying to solve this calculus exercise:

The Saint Louis arch can be approximated by using a function of the form $y=b-a\mathrm{cosh}(x/a)$. Putting the origin on the ground and in the center of the arch and the $y$-axis upward, find an approximate equation for the arch given these dimensions: height 615 and width 530. (in other words find $a$ and $b$).

Now from these data I got two equations:

$b-a=615$

$b-a\mathrm{cosh}(265/a)=0$

but I have no idea how to solve this system. Could you help me?

(that's not homework)

Comment: $530/2=265\ne275$.

Comment: ah yeah you're right

Answer (score 1):

Solve for $b$, getting $b = 615 + a$. Substitute into the non-linear equation:
$$
   615 + a = a \cdot \cosh \frac{265}{a}
$$
The equation is non-linear and is unlikely to admit a closed-form solution, but can be solved graphically (see for example [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7B215+%2B+a%2C+a+Cosh%5B265%2Fa%5D%7D+for+a+from+0+to+300)), or using [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), [getting](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FindRoot%5B215+%2B+a+%3D%3D+a+Cosh%5B265%2Fa%5D%2C%7Ba%2C200%7D%5D) $a = 191.192$.